# MariaDB 10.3 Randomly crash

Tags: linux, mysql, database, mariadb

I'm facing a very weird issue with a mariadb database, randomly it crash with this error:

```
free(): corrupted unsorted chunks
210804 20:05:16 [ERROR] mysqld got signal 6 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.

To report this bug, see https://mariadb.com/kb/en/reporting-bugs

We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed,
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.

Server version: 10.3.27-MariaDB-0+deb10u1
key_buffer_size=134217728
read_buffer_size=131072
max_used_connections=152
max_threads=153
thread_count=157
It is possible that mysqld could use up to
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 467424 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x7f2534000c08
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 0x7f260c2b9dd8 thread_stack 0x49000
```

I've already tried an fsck to the partitions and everything seems to be ok,
this just started to happen 2 weeks ago, and the server is operational since 3 months,

this server has a

sql_mode = ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
parameters on the my.cnf i don't know if this can really make mysqld crash in some situation.

Anyone have experience with similar problem?

Comment: Considering this package is provided by the Debian distribution, the very first step should be to have an up-to-date server: version 10.3.29-MariaDB-0+deb10u1 provided by package mariadb-server-core-10.3 version  1:10.3.29-0+deb10u1

Comment: @RickJames signal 6 (rather than errno 6) is SIGABRT.